# How can I change the default box in vagrant

Tags: docker, debian, cloud, vagrant, vagrantfile

I want to run vagrant up with provider is docker with command `vagrant up --provider=docker` in Mac M1.

The output is

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'docker' provider...
==> default: Box 'debian/bullseye64' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: docker
    default: Box Version: >= 0
==> default: Loading metadata for box 'debian/bullseye64'
    default: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/debian/bullseye64
The box you're attempting to add doesn't support the provider
you requested. Please find an alternate box or use an alternate
provider. Double-check your requested provider to verify you didn't
simply misspell it.

If you're adding a box from HashiCorp's Vagrant Cloud, make sure the box is
released.

Name: debian/bullseye64
Address: https://vagrantcloud.com/debian/bullseye64
Requested provider: [:docker]
```

Image debian/bullseye64 is not found, so I want to change the box to debian/bullseye. How can I do? Thank all!

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of things in your question:

- how to change the default box

If you open your Vagrantfile, you'll see you have something like

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  ...
  config.vm.box = "debian/bullseye64"
  ...
end
```

That is the place you need to change and replace by your new box name.

- There's no `debian/bullseye` box, so unless you have created this one yourself sitting on your laptop, you will not be able to use it
- You want to use docker so you need a box that runs on docker provider, you can search for such box in vagrant cloud like https://app.vagrantup.com/boxes/search?provider=docker